# Gherkin: Is it allowed to go back one step?

Tags: gherkin

When writing gherkin is it allowed to go back one step?

For example can I write Given - When - Then - **When** - Then?

If not - why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not allowed to go back a step.

Gherkin is not a Turing complete programming language. It doesn't support repetition or conditions.

You use Gherkin to describe a specific behaviour. A scenario with only one pass through. Therefore, you don't have a need for different execution paths in one scenario. If you need/want to describe another behaviour (execution path) you should write a another scenario.

This may feel like a way to create duplication and maybe it is. But it is also a way to create examples that are easy to understand and reason about. And most important, validate for a non programmer.

Answer (score 0):

If you literally mean going back to do the step again within the same scenario, this is a no, however, if you mean going back to use the words Given When Then And & But, then it is acceptable.

Meaning, you could write a scenario like:

```
Feature: This is a test

Scenario: I must write an example
 Given I do this
 And this should be done also
 Then I should see this
 When I do this
 Then I should see this
 When I do this other thing
 Then I should now see this
```

If you want to go backwards, there ***are*** 2 ways of doing it that are acceptable.

**Using a Scenario Outline**

```
Feature: This is a test

Scenario Outline: I must write an example
 Given I do this
 And this should be done also
 Then I should see this
 When I do <this>
 Then I should see <that>

Examples:
| this  | that  |
| this1 | that1 |
| this2 | that2 |
```

**Note** The Examples table uses a header row, that is used in the scenario outline above between these two brackets here: `<>`

**Using a Background**

```
Feature: This is a test

Background:
 Given I do this
 And this should be done also
 Then I should see this

Scenario: I must write an example
 When I do this
 Then I should see that

Scenario: I must write another example
 When I do this thing differs from the last scenario
 Then I should see thing which differs from the last scenario
```